# Don't find extension module in Python3

Tags: python-3.x, extension-methods

I'm doing a tutorial about the scipy ndimage in python3.6. I'm now at the point of C extending. According the tutorial i created this script:

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
import numpy

shift = Extension('example',
                  ['example.c'],
                  include_dirs=[numpy.get_include()]
)

setup(name='example',
      ext_modules=[shift]
)
```

But when i run the setup script i get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2862, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-79-18f2fcdde650>", line 10, in <module>
    ext_modules=[shift]
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/distutils/core.py", line 134, in setup
    ok = dist.parse_command_line()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 472, in parse_command_line
    args = self._parse_command_opts(parser, args)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 521, in _parse_command_opts
    raise SystemExit("invalid command name '%s'" % command)
SystemExit: invalid command name '49295'
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py:2870: UserWarning: To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.
  warn("To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.", stacklevel=1)
```

In some way setup() doesn't find the extension `shift`. I have looked at the documentation of [`disutils.core`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/distutils/apiref.html) but as far is can see it it looks i didn't something wrong... 
Can anybody explain what's goes wrong and why?

For the C script and the other scripts see: [Scipy ndimage extending](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/ndimage.html#extending-scipy-ndimage-in-c)

Comment: How are you running it?

Comment: Two ways: 1) copy-paste the script in python; run script from PyCharm Community edition (which returns _Process finished with exit code 1_)